# How to detect mouse and keyboard inactivity in linux

Tags: python, linux, input, keyboard, mouse

I am developing an app on python which will check for user inactivity. Is there a way to check for key press and mouse move events in linux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could monitor the /dev/input/* files, when a key is pressed/the mouse is moved it is written to one of those files.

Try this for example:

```
fh = file('/dev/input/mice')
while True:                 
    fh.read(3)
    print 'Mouse moved!'
```

Now that I think of it, it might be better to use something like [xidle](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/x11/xidle.html) to detect inactivity.

Comment: In Ubuntu Linux, `xautolock` is used instead

Comment: @ВасинЮрий There are several solutions, some don't require root rights but I'm not sure if they can be implemented in Python easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222606/detecting-keyboard-mouse-activity-in-linux

Comment: @Wolph, I can't find any working, even CLI (bash, shell) solution.

Comment: Have you tried the `xprintidle` app? It might work for you.

Comment: In Python3, this works: fh = open('/dev/input/mice', "rb")

Comment: Monitoring `/dev/input*` turned out to be the best solution out of all! Thank you! By the way, it fits perfectly for BASH to detect mouse *and* keyboard activity. Ex.: `sudo inotifywait --quiet /dev/input/event* /dev/input/mouse*` returns on any mouse or keyboard event.