# how to monitor the event of mouse or keyboard

Tags: linux, events

there. On Linux, is there any way in which I could shutdown the system if none action is taken by the user in some time(e.g. 30 minutes)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392076/how-to-detect-mouse-and-keyboard-inactivity-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get some property depends on her you can determinate idle state of user.
Write C application and determinate idle state of user if state is longer than 30minutes you can simply shutdown machine.