# Remote Linux Idle time of local user

Tags: linux, input, idle-timer

I'm looking for a way to determine the local input (mouse/keyboard) idle time,
remotely through SSH, *without having root access or access to the currently logged on user Xauthority*.

I know the following solution which works if you have access to the X server:
[detecting keyboard, mouse activity in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222606/detecting-keyboard-mouse-activity-in-linux)

But is it possible without having to connect to the X server? 
Is there another way? E.g. indirectly via CPU or memory usage of certain processes?
Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using w and /dev solutions will only get you so far, since it could be that the user is around, but has not typed anything in the shell - for example, he/she could be playing some game. A better approach would be to poll /proc/interrupts. The local interrupts for the mouse and keyboard are often under "i8042" (though in some rare cases it might be different). You might want to try: "grep i8042 /proc/interrupts". This will yield IRQ 1 (keyboard) and IRQ 12 (usually, the mouse). You can get the values, store them, and then poll occasionally (no callback, alas), to get the counts. If the numbers changed, interrupts occurred - meaning keyboard (IRQ 1) or mouse (IRQ 12) were touched/pressed etc. Key presses generally generate two interrupts (key down, key up). Mouse movement is more erratic.

This has several advantages:

1) If the user so much as touches the mouse, or presses a key - you know
2) You can do so programmatically (i.e. fopen() /proc/interrupts , or  (alternatively) /proc/stat, and get the "intr" line) and fread() the relevant lines
3) You don't even need to be root for this.

Comment: This is cool. Although it seems that it does not work with USB keyboard/mouse right?

Comment: I just checked, there are also usb interrupts. However they occur on a regular basis. So I can subtract this rate to see if there are additional events. This should work.

Comment: Won't work with USB, correct, but USB is still an interrupt source. So yes. The correlation may not be 1:1 like it is with i8042, but - all the same - you will get a non-zero value when user is active - which is what you wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As an unprivileged, distinct user, I'd try to do this by monitoring for new processes spawned with the target user ID.  If you see a new process, chances are it means the user caused it to be spawned, unless its parent is cron (or one of a handful of similar supervisors, you'll have to try it on your system and filter out the few false alarms you get at first).

This won't give you a very precise idle time, but perhaps a maximum bound.  If you want something more precise, you probably ought to have privileges to do it.

Comment: A user can be active (writing something in an editor) without creating new processes

Answer (score 1):

The commands `w` and `ls -l /dev/pts` are the best ones I can think of. Between them, you can get a pretty good view of idleness on the linux console, ssh, and xterm sessions.

If the user is just sitting on a local thing playing with firefox or something, this won't catch it, but I'm not sure you can get that without access to X or being root. Looking for cpu usage isn't reliable because a lot of apps use a little cpu even when idle, or virtually zero when used, and watching /proc/x_server_pid/* doesn't help either, since X can still have activity even when the user is idle.

Looking for new processes like the other answer said is the best I can think of if /dev/pts doesn't help and you can't actually look at the input.